# Var-Arg , multi-dimensional array

Tags: java, arrays, variadic-functions

whenever I am passing two 1-d arrays as an argument to 2-d var-arg method then it works fine but if I try to pass same two 1-d arrays to a method with a simple 2-d argument then it gives me error -   **`The method m1(int[][]) in the type Asd is not applicable for the arguments (int[], int[])`**.

As per my knowledge int[]... ==> int[][], then what is the reason behind this behaviour?

**Var-Arg Method**

```
public class Asd {


    public static void main(String[] args) {


        m1(new int[] {6,7},new int[] {8,9});

    }

    public static void m1(int[]... b)
    {

        System.out.println(b[0][0]);

    }
}
```

**Simple Method** :-

```
public class Asd {


    public static void main(String[] args) {


        m1(new int[] {6,7},new int[] {8,9});

    }

    public static void m1(int[][] b)
    {

        System.out.println(b[0][0]);

    }
}
```

Comment: `int[][]` is not `int[], int[]`

Comment: @Guy but when i am passing int[],int[] to var-arg method, it creates a 2-d array.
Also, why there is a difference in behavior of var-arg and simple method

Comment: You can observe the same behavior with 1D arrays. You can't pass two `int`s to a method that expects an `int[]` (unless you create an array that contains those 2 `int`s), but you can pass those two `int`s to a method that expects an `int...`.

Comment: Because varargs stores the values in array from all the values passed to it, in your case array of arrays.

Comment: @Eran - got it bro thanks

Comment: @bharat the reason is that you can only use varargs if the method is declared as a varargs method. That's just the way the language is specified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When multiple argument is passed to the method java compiler might be converting code to pass as array of object of given type.

That's the reason when you try to pass multiple parameter and receiving type is not var-args then compiler will complain about different data types.As they are not compatible with each other.

You can still pass parameter's by creating 2-D array:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    m1( new int[][]{new int[]{6, 7}, new int[]{8, 9}} );
}

private static void m1(int[][] b) {
    System.out.println( b[0][0] );
}
```